Spanning 4K wallpapers Windows 11 shifted down
I have a dual 4K display setup.  What I had was an image of 16:9 resolution which I set to use Span on Windows.  As expected on my 3840x2160 image, the image is shifted so it starts at row 540 and shows until row 1620 at least until a recent Windows 11 update (build 26100).
The reason is if I switch to single monitor I would like to keep the same image.
I sent it a post on Feedback Hub already, but I am not sure if I am not the only one experiencing this.

"until a recent Windows update" and "as expected": Could you clarify what these mean? Are you saying that this is normal behavior that you just don't like? How are the monitors oriented? What update? Please add the requested clarifications to the question itself to make it better and more clear.

i noted it now build 26100, 3 months ago
